Keep Getting "Cannot access attribute "Table" " for boto3 resource
I'm learning AWS Lambda and there is a section of Python code we need to use and it is using boto3, however when I paste the code into my code editor, it gives me an error right off the bat. The compete error is this:
Cannot access attribute "Table" for class "_"  Attribute "Table" is unknown
The code itself is this:
import boto3
table_name = "lambda-apigateway"
dynamo = boto3.resource('dynamodb').Table(table_name) -- ERROR IS HERE

Something to note is that when I paste the code into VScode the error goes away, maybe it's because I'm using a different Lsp? Thanks if you could help, also this is my first post so some feedback to incorporate in my future posts would be appreciated.
Here is the entire code snippit:
import boto3

# Define the DynamoDB table that Lambda will connect to
table_name = "lambda-apigateway"

# Create the DynamoDB resource
dynamo = boto3.resource('dynamodb').Table(table_name)

# Define some functions to perform the CRUD operations
def create(payload):
    return dynamo.put_item(Item=payload['Item'])

def read(payload):
    return dynamo.get_item(Key=payload['Key'])

def update(payload):
    return dynamo.update_item(**{k: payload[k] for k in ['Key', 'UpdateExpression', 
    'ExpressionAttributeNames', 'ExpressionAttributeValues'] if k in payload})

def delete(payload):
    return dynamo.delete_item(Key=payload['Key'])

def echo(payload):
    return payload

operations = {
    'create': create,
    'read': read,
    'update': update,
    'delete': delete,
    'echo': echo,
}

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    '''Provide an event that contains the following keys:
      - operation: one of the operations in the operations dict below
      - payload: a JSON object containing parameters to pass to the 
        operation being performed
    '''
    
    operation = event['operation']
    payload = event['payload']
    
    if operation in operations:
        return operations[operation](payload)
        
    else:
        raise ValueError(f'Unrecognized operation "{operation}"')

And the tutorial that I am currently following: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway-tutorial.html#services-apigateway-tutorial-prereqs
I am expecting that the code will not have an error there, but I am not sure if that error will be there regardless of what I do.

Since  python3 has no inherent typing itself, it falls on individual libraries to and yes, sometimes IDEs, to provide typing hints.  I'm guessing VSCode is just better at it than neovim.  I learned recently from the python guys at work that boto3 is apparently one of the more poorly typed libraries out there.  It also makes heavy use of dictionaries in responses, so typing won't be super useful.

@erik258 "I'm guessing VSCode is just better at it than neovim.": The most popular Python language server for Neovim is Pyright, whereas that of VSCode is Pylance, a (proprietary) fork of Pyright. If anything, it's likely that Pylance's type checking mode is set to basic or off.

@erik258 ya that's what I figured, thanks for the help :)

Does it happen when you use boto3.client instead of boto3.resource?

@Shameel Wow, ya that worked, thanks for the help!!

@SebastianMartinez, I am making this an answer so that others can get benefited out of it. Please make it as answered.

The resources abstraction seems to have been deprecated. Use the client abstraction.
Source: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/resources.html

The AWS Python SDK team does not intend to add new features to the
resources interface in boto3. Existing interfaces will continue to
operate during boto3’s lifecycle. Customers can find access to newer
service features through the client interface.

Replace
dynamo = boto3.resource('dynamodb').Table(table_name) -- ERROR IS HERE

with
dynamo = boto3.client('dynamodb').Table(table_name)

